# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: in laravel livewire project

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-livewire

I am trying to sync the navigation menu with navigation type but I'm getting the error `Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' navigation_menu_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into 'navigation_menus_navigation_types' (' navigation_menu_id', 'navigation_type_id') values (1, 1))`

I am not sure why navigation_menu_id is not found. I am using a custom pivot table with custom foreign key id.

**Migration.php*

```
Schema::create('navigation_menus_navigation_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id('navigation_menus_navigation_types_id');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('navigation_menu_id');
$table->foreign('navigation_menu_id')->references('navigation_menus_id')->on('navigation_menus');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('navigation_type_id');
$table->foreign('navigation_type_id')->references('navigation_menu_types_id')->on('navigation_menu_types');
$table->timestamps(); });
```

**NavigationMenu Model.php**

```
class NavigationMenu extends Model {
protected $primaryKey = 'navigation_menus_id';

public function navigationType()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(NavigationMenuType::class,'navigation_menus_navigation_types','navigation_type_id',' navigation_menu_id');
}}
```

**Navigation Menu Type Model.php**

```
class NavigationMenuType extends Model{
protected $primaryKey = 'navigation_menu_types_id';

public function navigationMenu()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(NavigationMenu::class,'navigation_menus_navigation_types',' navigation_menu_id','navigation_type_id');
}}
```

**PagesNavigation Controller.php**

```
public function syncNavtypes(){
        $this->seletedNavigationMenu = NavigationMenu::find($this->navMenuId);
        $this->seletedNavigationMenu->navigationType()->sync($this->navTypeId);
        $this->modelSyncNavigationTypesVisible = false;
        $this->reset();
        $this->resetValidation();}
```

Comment: Voting to close this question because its a typo, with an extra space at `' navigation_menu_id'` in your `NavigationMenu` model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in your relation:

```
public function navigationType()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(NavigationMenuType::class,'navigation_menus_navigation_types','navigation_type_id',
' navigation_menu_id');  // here!!
}
```

the thing is that you have added extra space to the begin of the column name,
currently laravel will take it to the letter!!

you have to just remove the extra space.

```
public function navigationType()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(NavigationMenuType::class,'navigation_menus_navigation_types','navigation_type_id',
'navigation_menu_id');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed if there's no additional issue. You'd put an extra space in your relation -

```
' navigation_menu_id'

return $this->belongsToMany(NavigationMenuType::class,'navigation_menus_navigation_types','navigation_type_id','navigation_menu_id');
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I had a space there

Comment: that's typing mistake. :)